# Stored procedures written in MySQL 5.5.8 don't work in 5.1

Tags: mysql, sql

I have some stored procedures and a trigger that work great in MySQL 5.5.8 but for some reason don't work in 5.1.  The error descriptions aren't enough for me to figure out the problem.  Here is the code and the errors.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `cg_getMatchingContent`( 
MatchTerm VARCHAR(255),
MaxResults INT)
BEGIN
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT t.*, INSTR(t.`Title`,MatchTerm) as Pos 
    FROM cg_content t ) c
WHERE Pos>0 ORDER BY Pos LIMIT 0, MaxResults;

END
```

Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'MaxResults' at line 8

```
DELIMITER ;;
CREATE TRIGGER `cg`.`cg_content_UrlDup_ConstTrig`
BEFORE INSERT ON `cg`.`cg_content`
FOR EACH ROW
Begin
DECLARE errorString VARCHAR(500);
DECLARE insert_error CONDITION FOR SQLSTATE '99001';      

IF new.Url = '' THEN
        SET errorString = CONCAT('Url cannot be blank
Title: ' , new.Title);  
     SIGNAL insert_error
        SET MESSAGE_TEXT=errorString; 
END if;

IF Exists(SELECT id FROM cg.cg_content WHERE Url=new.Url) THEN
     SET errorString = CONCAT('Url is not unique
Title: ' , new.Title  , '
Url: ' + new.Url);
     SIGNAL insert_error
        SET MESSAGE_TEXT=errorString;

End if;
End ;;
```

Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'insert_error
            SET MESSAGE_TEXT=errorString;END if;IF ' at line 10

Comment: It would be so great if `MySQL 5.1` would emit meaningful errors, like: "Seems you are trying to use a local variable in LIMIT. Sorry, we do not support this feature yet. Please wait for release 5.5.6".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second one is easy to figure, hard to fix. `SIGNAL` and `RESIGNAL` commands were introduced in MySQL 5.5. You can't convert it easily to 5.1. One way to do it, would be to run a query that errors. For example a `SELECT` from a non-existent table.

Answer (score 4):

From the [docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/select.html):

> Within stored programs, `LIMIT` parameters can be specified using integer-valued routine parameters or local variables as of `MySQL 5.5.6`.

`5.1` does not support variables in `LIMIT` and `OFFSET`.

Comment: Could be fixed by creating a prepared statement within the procedure

Comment: Thanks for the quick response.  I wish I could give both you and Mchl the correct answer but I'm just going to flip a coin

Comment: @i8abug: Mchl proposed a fix for my problem and I haven't done the same for his one.